# Windows 10 datavirtualization with datagrid and rowdetails

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, data-virtualization

I'm using a datagrid with rowdetails with it's ItemsSource bound to an AsynchronousVirtualizingCollection based on this project by [Paul McClean](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) . Using Windows 7, .Net Framework 4.5 I had trouble when selecting rows in the grid, the entire collection was being fetched when it was not necessary. I found a solution to this problem using a datawrapper as described in [this project](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/378#.Vl2r3vkveUk) . This worked fine for me. Now I upgraded my system to Windows 10, still using the same framework. The selection still works fine but when i want to show the row details, the entire collection is being fetched again. This doesn't happen on a Windows 7 system. Has anyone encountered the same problems or does anyone have an explanation why it works on Windows 7 and not on Windows 10? Thank you